# Maximum call stack size exceeded, Observberjs GSAP

Tags: gsap

I am learning GSAP implementation on reactjs using this reference https://greensock.com/get-started

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import { ScrollTrigger } from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";
import { Observer } from "gsap/Observer";
import { PixiPlugin } from "gsap/PixiPlugin.js";
import { MotionPathPlugin } from "gsap/MotionPathPlugin.js";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const sectionsRef = useRef([]);
  const imagesRef = useRef([]);
  const headingsRef = useRef([]);
  const outerWrappersRef = useRef([]);
  const innerWrappersRef = useRef([]);
  const animatingRef = useRef(false);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);
  const wrap = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      const length = sectionsRef.current.length;
      console.log(length);
      return ((value % length) + length) % length;
    }, [sectionsRef]
  );

  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
  gsap.registerPlugin(Observer);
  gsap.registerPlugin(PixiPlugin, MotionPathPlugin);


  useEffect(() => {
    sectionsRef.current = document.querySelectorAll("section");
    imagesRef.current = document.querySelectorAll(".bg");
    headingsRef.current = gsap.utils.toArray(".section-heading");
    outerWrappersRef.current = gsap.utils.toArray(".outer");
    innerWrappersRef.current = gsap.utils.toArray(".inner");

    gsap.set(outerWrappersRef.current, { yPercent: 100 });
    gsap.set(innerWrappersRef.current, { yPercent: -100 });

    Observer.create({
      type: "wheel,touch,pointer",
      wheelSpeed: -1,
      onDown: () => !animatingRef.current && gotoSection(currentIndex - 1, -1),
      onUp: () => !animatingRef.current && gotoSection(currentIndex + 1, 1),
      tolerance: 100,
      preventDefault: true,
    });
    gotoSection(0, 1);
  }, [currentIndex]);

  function gotoSection(index, direction) {
    index = wrap(index);
    animatingRef.current = true;

    let fromTop = direction === -1,
      dFactor = fromTop ? -1 : 1,
      tl = gsap.timeline({
        defaults: { duration: 1.25, ease: "power1.inOut" },
        onComplete: () => animatingRef.current = false
      });

    if (currentIndex >= 0) {
      gsap.set(sectionsRef.current[currentIndex], { zIndex: 0 });

      tl.to(imagesRef.current[currentIndex], { yPercent: -0 * dFactor }).set(
        sectionsRef.current[currentIndex],
        { autoAlpha: 0 }
      );
    }

    gsap.set(sectionsRef.current[index], { autoAlpha: 1, zIndex: 1 });

    tl.fromTo(
      [outerWrappersRef.current[index], innerWrappersRef.current[index]],
      { yPercent: (i) => (i ? -100 * dFactor : 100 * dFactor) },
      { yPercent: 0 },
      0
    );

    setCurrentIndex(index);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <section className="first">
        <div className="outer">
          <div className="inner">
            <div className="bg one">
              <h2 className="section-heading">Scroll down</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section className="second">
        <div className="outer">
          <div className="inner">
            <div className="bg">
              <h2 className="section-heading">Animated with GSAP</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default App
```

If I scroll up, I will have this error

```
Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at _integrate2 (Observer.js:49:18)
    at _setScrollTrigger2 (Observer.js:204:42)
    at Function._initCore2 [as register] (Observer.js:227:5)
    at _createPlugin2 (gsap-core.js:1060:29)
    at gsap-core.js:4098:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.registerPlugin (gsap-core.js:4097:10)
    at
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Did you ever find the cause? I'm having the same problem outside of React.